# Get upstream sections of a network

Tags: qgis, network, hydrology

Is there any extension to get all upstream sections of a polyline shapefile which represent an hydrographic network in QGIS?

It could work like this:

- you choose a specific branch and a direction
- then the algorithm will select all the sections recursively until you have all the branches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Flow trace" plugin in QGIS. Take any river network, select a segment of river and press flow trace icon to get all upstream rivers selected.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in QGiS using the GRASS tools.

1. It is merely convert *line to point* > upstream area (r.water.outlet) - > *Convert to Polygon* > *Selection*.
2. Use the netowrk vector tools to get upstream lines. The Grass implementation is (https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_extract_upstream_network)
3. USe the [Stream Reac](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/taudem/stream_network_analysis_tools/streamreachandwatershed.html)h tool in QGIS.